# Validate a single field in django without using Form or models

Tags: python, django, validation

I am using django to fill some forms, I know how to use Forms and use validation but my forms are complicated and it is hard to create Forms object from those forms. I wanted to know is there any way to use validators on a parameter which I get from POST in a view?

For example I have a feild which is named `user` then

```
def login_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user=request.POST["user"]
        # check whether it's valid without using forms
```

I know about validators https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/ and it seems they only works on `models` and `forms`. Is it even possible to validate a single field? If not what other options do I have for complex forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Validator is just a function that receives the form value and does nothing if the value is valid or raises an ValidationError in case it is not valid.

You can just import a Validator into your view and call it there.

With a Validator called `custom_validate_user` this might look like that:

```
def login_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user=request.POST["user"]
        try:
            custom_validate_user(user)
        except ValidationError as e:
            # handle the validation error
```

Nevertheless - if you have complex forms your views may become messy if you handle whole the validation directly in place. Therefore you usually encapsulate this logic in a form, or ensure validation on model level.

Comment: thanks very much. well I do not want to use forms as they are hard to change their templates and also adding custom controls, can not I use sth like controllers to avoid messy views? I am confused when I see there is not any controllers and I have no idea where to perform these kind of takes, in views or models

Comment: @MajidHojati Form doesnt force you to use it in template, you can make html forms as you like but also validate them. So you have wrong approach I strongly unrecommend you to follow it.

Comment: @Denis really? can you please provide me a link about using html forms and validating using forms?it is a great approach

Comment: just provide proper values for input attr "name", try to generate simple django form in shell for example and see html output, Im not sure because didnt work with native forms for a long time but they have format like "id_YOUR-MODEL-FIELD-NAME" so model field last_name turns in <input name="id_last_name"> and so on and it will work on backend as usual

Comment: The official [documentation about django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `MyUser` model you can define your validators inside it and reuse it whenever you need.

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

def validate_str_starts_with_uppercase(value: str):
    if value and not value[0].isupper()
        raise ValidationError("Should start with uppercase")

validate_str_no_whitespace = RegexValidator(
    regex=r"^\S*$",
    message="Should not contain whitespace",
)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        validators=[validate_str_no_whitespace, validate_str_starts_with_uppercase],
    )
```

A function to call validators of one field (similar to `model.clean_fields()` but run on one field):

```py
from django.db import models
from typing import Type, Union

def run_field_validators(model_type: Union[models.Model, Type[models.Model]], field_name: str, raw_value: Any) -> None:
    """
    Validate `raw_value` with the validators of one field of the model.

    Similar to `model.clean_fields()` but runs on only one field and validates the given `raw_value`.

    :param model_type: A model class or instance
    :param field_name: Name of the field to validate
    :param raw_value: Value to be validated
    :raises ValidationError: If value is not valid
    """
    if isinstance(model_type, models.Model):
        class_ = model_type.__class__
    else:
        class_ = model_type
    field = class_._meta.get_field(field_name)
    value = field.to_python(raw_value)

    # Raise error if field value is blank (and if field.blank==False).
    # This is needed here because field.run_validators ignores blank values.
    if not field.blank and value in field.empty_values:
        raise ValidationError(field.error_messages["blank"], code="blank")

    field.run_validators(value)
```

Use it:

```py
def login_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name=request.POST["user"]
        run_field_validators(MyUser, "name", user_name)
```